# ArrayList of PreparedStatements

Tags: java, jdbc, arraylist

I just wondering if I declare `ArrayList<PreparedStatement> ps = new ArrayList<>();` and add statements using this method.

```
public void addQuery(String query){
    try{
            Connection con = connect();
            PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.add(p);
    } catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

Does the connection and PreparedStatements stored in the `ArrayList<>` will be closed if I call the `ps.clear` method? I tried this

```
public void addQuery(String query){
    try(Connection con = connect(); PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement(query);){
            ps.add(p);
    }
}
```

but when I execute the `PreparedStatements` stored in the `ArrayList<>`, I get the error

> No operations allowed after statement closed.

what is the best thing to do?

Comment: The best thing to do would be to forget about putting `PreparedStatements` in a list. I don't know what you're trying to achieve with it, but it doesn't make any sense and will only make your code unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: **Never** write `catch (Exception e){

    }` elways handle exceptions properbly

Comment: The ArrayList will be used for executing many different queries

Comment: That sounds like a bad approach. Remember the last problem you had with it? You're only making your code more brittle. Try using the standard idioms before you start inventing your own "clever" solutions.

Comment: That `ps.clear()` means `st.close()`, as used by the try-with-resource statement...

Comment: Why can't you store the queries into ArrayList<String>, instead of storing prepared statements?

Comment: Both `List<String>` and `List<PreparedStatement>` looses the potential to use bound parameters...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto `ArrayList.clear()` has exactly nothing to do with `PreparedStatement.close()`.

Comment: @EJP Yeah, i was fooled by the variable name `ps`, thought it was a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto `PreparedStatement` doesn't have a `clear()` method. Your comment about losing bound parameters is also incorrect, but as the whole thing doesn't work it's irrelevant.

Comment: @Kayaman well sorry for my being a bad programmer, i'm just a student.

Comment: You don't have to be sorry. It's just that you're doing things in a non-standard way, which is not a good thing if you're learning. When you understand how to do things properly, then you can come up with more "exotic" approaches, since you understand what and why you're doing them. I say forget the list and do it in the idiomatic way. You can find plenty of tutorials on JDBC (just make sure you follow a good and recent one).

Comment: @SedrickJefferson Only as regards the title. Actual question is quite different, as are the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the connection and `PreparedStatements stored in the`ArrayList<>`will be closed if I call the`ps.clear()` method?

No. Clearing an array has nothing to do with what the array contains. But all the prepared statements will be closed as soon as you close them or the connection(s) they were created from, which happened as a result of the try-with resources statement, which is why you got that exception.

Which is also why this is pointless.

One of the whole points of prepared statements is to give the connection pool, or the JDBC driver, or the database server itself, an opportunity to cache them. You don't need to do it yourself.

Comment: so how the connections stored in the preparedStatement of the ArrayList will be closed?

Comment: By the try-with-resources statement, as I have already clearly stated. That syntax has *no other purpose* but to ensure the resource is closed when it exits. Hard to see why you're using it if you don't know what it does.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, PreparedStatement in **try/catch** block is the same as in your ps list. When you add object to list, it doesn't get copied, list holds reference to original object. So when you close connection, it gets closed everywhere.

Secondly, 'ps.clear()' doesn't close your connection, it just removes reference to your connection object from list, so you can't rely on `clear()` closing your connection. Hope this helps.